# Multiple Count with Multiple column

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new in sql. I want to count something like:

```
Select count(*) from table where col1= x and col2=x and Col3=x.
```

I need to count the same value in all different column. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation :

```
Select sum(case when col1='x' then 1 else 0 end) as count_col1,
       sum(case when col2='x' then 1 else 0 end) as count_col2,
       sum(case when col3='x' then 1 else 0 end) as count_col3
  from tab;
```

If you want to have sum of these count values, consider the above query as an inner and use the following :

```
 Select q.*,
        q.count_col1 + q.count_col2 + q.count_col3 whole_sum
   from     
     (
        Select sum(case when col1='x' then 1 else 0 end) as count_col1,
               sum(case when col2='x' then 1 else 0 end) as count_col2,
               sum(case when col3='x' then 1 else 0 end) as count_col3
          from tab  
      ) q
```

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/JSQWL88751)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do I can sum of all the columns value as well?

Comment: @AyesaJannat Welcome, yes, sure depending on your data's syntax.

Comment: What to do for having the total of 3 columns count?

Comment: Wow!! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @AyesaJannat if you think the answer helped, kindly please mark it.

Comment: Even simpler is sum the conditions without `case`: `sum(col1='x') as count_col1`,

Comment: @Parfait exactly, nice catch.